# Disappearing subtemplate

Tags: django

One of my django subtemplates just mysteriously stopped rendering. I reverted to previous commits and other branches where I knew it worked fine, and it doesn't show up. I tried in other browsers and restarted everything. There are no error messages, but the Django debug toolbar doesn't show it loading. Any ideas? So weird.

(when it stopped, I was working neither on the subtemplate or the template that calls it--neither file was open)

Comment: What's not rendering? The context?

Comment: Nothing at all--just an empty space where it should be (it's a navigation bar)

Comment: What were you working on when it broke?

Comment: Something entirely different--I found the bug though.  Apparently I got logged out somehow, and the template that allows me to login doesn't render unless I'm logged in.  What a silly bug.  Thanks!

Comment: Weird. Glad you got it working!